# Wordpress repeatable group of metabox

Tags: php, wordpress

what code spinet i use in page.php to show data in frontend.

```
array(
'id'          => $prefix . 'repeat_group',
'type'        => 'group',
'description' => __( 'Generates reusable form entries', 'cmb' ),
'options'     => array(
    'group_title'   => __( 'Entry {#}', 'cmb' ), // since version 1.1.4, {#} gets replaced by row number
    'add_button'    => __( 'Add Another Entry', 'cmb' ),
    'remove_button' => __( 'Remove Entry', 'cmb' ),
    'sortable'      => true, // beta
),
// Fields array works the same, except id's only need to be unique for this group. Prefix is not needed.
'fields'      => array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Entry Title',
        'id'   => 'title',
        'type' => 'text',
        // 'repeatable' => true, // Repeatable fields are supported w/in repeatable groups (for most types)
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Description',
        'description' => 'Write a short description for this entry',
        'id'   => 'description',
        'type' => 'textarea_small',
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Entry Image',
        'id'   => 'image',
        'type' => 'file',
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Image Caption',
        'id'   => 'image_caption',
        'type' => 'text',
    ),
),
```

),

above code taken from:

```
https://github.com/WebDevStudios/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress/wiki/Field-Types#group
```

I did not find any way how i can put it in page.php and show data in front end page.

Thank for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to have repeatable metaboxes in the WordPress admin, is to use ACF (http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) with the repeater field (http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/repeater-field/)

it gives a really nice end product, its easy to use/implement, it has good support, and can be bundled with any theme/plugin as long as you follow the instructions for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm you repeatable group set up would perfectly work with [CMB2](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cmb2/) (with attention to a few enhancements), check it on [Github](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2) too for more details.

The link you provided refers to an old version of the plugin, which is now named CMB2, it is indeed a great Custom Fields plugin for WordPress, you can install and use it as any ordinary plugin, or you could bootstrap it within your own theme.

You mentioned that your theme seems to already have another fields than the ones you want to set up, right?, if that's true, this leads me to think that your theme might be requiring (including) a `.php` file somewhere which is responsible for initiating CMB2 and the Custom Fields set up. It also might take place on your theme's `functions.php` file. So again, if that's the case, the right place to put the code you provided is inside this specific file which you'd need to identify, and not the `page.php` template.

When you set up Custom Fields and Group of Fields with CMB2 you then define an array of object types for which the fields would be available for, it can be a page, post, post type and even a taxonomy term.

I'll reference my own use case here for the purpose of exemplifying the fields set up. I use the following code to display a Group of Fields with pricing options for all posts of type `restaurant_menu`, but it's up to you to define the objects your fields offers support to. e.g: `'object_types'  => array( 'page, post, post_type' )`

--//--

```
    /**
     * Example Repeatable Group - Pricing Options Custom Fields // with Repeatable Fields within the group
     */               
    $cmb_group = new_cmb2_box( array(
      'id'            => $prefix . 'example_price_box',
      'title'         => __( 'Pricing Options', 'mytheme' ),
      'object_types'  => array( 'restaurant_menu' ),
    ) );

    // Parent
    $group_field_id = $cmb_group->add_field( array(
      'id'          => $prefix . 'example_price_group',
      'type'        => 'group',
      'options'     => array(
      'group_title'   => __( 'Price Box {#}', 'mytheme' ), // translatable 
      'add_button'    => __( 'Add New Price Box', 'mytheme' ),
      'remove_button' => __( 'Remove Price Box', 'mytheme' ),
      'sortable'      => true, // beta
    ),

    ) );

    // Price Label
    $cmb_group->add_group_field( $group_field_id, array(
      'name' => __( 'Price Legend', 'pivot'),
      'desc' => __( 'Set a short legend for the price. e.g Small, Large, 4 slices, 500g etc.', 'my theme'),
      'id'   => 'price_title',
      'type' => 'text_small',
      'repeatable' => true, // Repeatable fields are supported w/in repeatable groups (for most types)
      'options' => array( 'add_row_text' => __( 'Add New Legend', 'mytheme' ) ),
    ) );

    // Price Label Description
    $cmb_group->add_group_field( $group_field_id, array(
      'name' => __( 'Price Description', 'mytheme' ),
      'desc' => __( 'A very short description for the price legend.', 'mytheme'),
      'id'   => 'price_desc',
      'type' => 'text_medium',
      'after_field'  => __( '<p><b>E.g.</b> "Serves up to 4 people", "Made with Premium Cheese" etc.</p>', 'mytheme'),
      //'repeatable' => true, // Repeatable fields are supported w/in repeatable groups (for most types)
      //'show_in_rest'  => true, // expose field to WP REST API / Under CMB2 Development - please check for CMB2 on Github
      //'show_in_rest'  => array( 'read_and_write', 'write_only' ), true, // expose field to WP REST API using an array of permission types
    ) );          

    // Price Amount
    $cmb_group->add_group_field( $group_field_id, array(
      'name' => __( 'Product Price', 'mytheme' ),
      'desc' => __( 'Set the price for the item. Use , to separate decimals.', 'pivot'),
      'id'   => 'price_tag',
      'type' => 'text_money',
      'before_field' => '$', // override '$' symbol if needed
      //'repeatable' => true, // Repeatable fields are supported w/in repeatable groups (for most types)
    ) );
```

As for now CMB2 supports a lot of field types (including repeatable fields and groups), and it has dozens of 3rd party add ons (extensions) to choose for, most of those completely free. It is well maintained and it is absolutely easy to set up. I use it on my theme and I don't even think to replace it anytime soon.